# Searching for Martin Gardner / Dr. Matrix reference

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, infinite-games

In a recent interview on Robinson's Podcast, Joel David Hamkins described an infinite game he called "The chocolatier and the glutton" (also at this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400967/an-infinite-game-possibly-due-to-ernst-specker/401136#401136)). The 2 player alternate-move game in simplest form is that the chocolatier creates however (finitely) many chocolates he wants on his turn, while the glutton eats exactly one chocolate on his turn. The glutton wins if he consumes all the chocolates, otherwise the chocolatier wins. (See the link for the strategy and variations.)

When I heard this game described, I felt sure that I had read of this game (with a different framing but same substance) eons ago as a throwaway joke in one of Martin Gardner's Dr. Matrix columns. I've looked for it via google, but no luck. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: What is the *math* question here?

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Magic_Numbers_of_Dr_Matrix/-E0FEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Kurt G, the math question is, in effect, about the history of this particular infinite game described by JDH. Will Jagy, are you indicating that the game is described somewhere in that collection of Dr. Matrix columns? I asked the q b/c I was hoping that someone could do better than tell me to "reread all the old Sci Am columns".

Comment: @KurtG. M.SE has tags like (reference-request), (recreational-mathematics), (math-history), (education), etc. because such questions are welcome and on-topic for this site, even if they are not math proper per se. (The last two tags I mentioned might be more relevant to HSM.SE or ME.SE, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: It sounds like [Chomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp).

Comment: in Chomp both player eat chocolate.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle: may the "game" you are thinging of be the one in which on move $N$ the first player puts balls from $10N-9$ to $10N$ in an urn, while the second one removes ball numbered $N?$ After an infinite number of moves, there will be no ball in the urn since ball $k$ was removed at move $k$. I think this is actually present in one of Gardner's columns sporting Dr Matrix.

Comment: @mau, yes that might be it. Would love it if you have a reference to the actual column. Thanks!

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle: I browser Martin Gardner's book on Dr Matrix. but I coud not find a reference. Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle Not a direct reference but see this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25910) to [A problem of an infinite number of balls and an urn](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7063/a-problem-of-an-infinite-number-of-balls-and-an-urn) on MO.